# Get element reference without using refs in react

Tags: reactjs

I am told refs are likely to be deprecated.

How then could I achieve the following, considering this code:

```
export default class DemoAxis extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      const el = this.refs.line;

      const dimensions = .getDimensionsFromElement(el);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div ref="line">
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I need a reference to the line div to get dimensions from it.

I know there is a ref callback, should I be using that?

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only [string refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute) are considered for deprecation, you can still use [callback refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute):

```
export default class DemoAxis extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {   
      const dimensions = .getDimensionsFromElement(this._line);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div ref={ (ref) => this._input = ref }>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Or in your case, you don't need a ref, just get the DOM node from the component `this`, using [`ReactDOM.findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode) ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ngx5wbbu/)):

```
componentDidMount() {
    const dimensions = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(dimensions);
},
```

Comment: thanks for the `findDOMNode()` alternative, you need this in the case that your `DemoAxis` uses a function component as its `render()` output (you can't use `createRef()` then)